# Getting notification when firewall settings have changed

Tags: network, notifications, firewall, pfctl

I'm using packet filter engine to setup my Firewall connection. However, there might be other entities that may override my firewall settings on the same way (processes running with 'root' privileges and using `pfctl` with different `.pf` files).

Is there a way to detect such change of configuration, I can periodically extract list of currently applied rules, but I prefer to get a notification.

thanks,

Comment: You can write a cron script that make a diff between the list of current rules and a file containing the previous rules. The script could send you a mail in case of change.